# Looking for a function to impute missing values according to the ratio of other values in R.(looking for probability based)

Tags: r, imputation

I have a data frame with over 9000 data points and 3 columns have nearly 1000(each) missing values. I am trying to make a function to impute them according to the proportion of other values.I am not looking for most common method(mode).After I found the missing value=1000(each column),I tried to distribute values from other rows in that particular column according to their proportion.Suppose a column has ratio of "a" and "b" as 50:50 and 4 missing values.I will fill those missing values according to the ratio so 2a and 2b.

Comment: What is `a` in the `d = data.frame(a, b)`

Comment: Look, you didn't use imputation. `group_indices` creates an index based on a group, and since you didn't provide any group, it assumed all data is just one group. So, when you use `createDataPartition` you just selected all the data again. There's no change in the data here, and `table` by default doesn't show `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand the question but here are some things to try.

You can tabulate the values of b, including NAs

```
library(tidyverse)
a = c(1:12)
b = c("a", "a", "b", "c", 
      "a", "c", "b", NA, 
      "b", "c", "a", "a")

df = tibble(a = a, b = b)
df %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% 
  summarise(n())
```

Or, using table

```
table(b, useNA = 'always')

#a    b    c <NA> 
#5    3    3    1
```

To replace the missing value by the most common non-missing value

```
tab <- table(b)
replacment <- names(which.max(tab))

df %>% 
  mutate(b = if_else(is.na(b), replacment, b))
```